# PHP, сортировка массива и подсчет "максимальных" значений в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Доброго времени суток, дня и ночи.

Имеется массив вида:

> ```
>    $array = [
>       1     => [
>           'count'   => 15,
>           'price'   => 974190,
>       ],
>       2     => [
>           'count'   => 13,
>           'price'   => 312561,
>       ],
>       3     => [
>           'count'   => 55,
>           'price'   => 12512,
>       ],
>       4     => [
>           'count'   => 14,
>           'price'   => 3125,
>       ]
>     ];
> ```

Мне необходимо выяснить в каких вложенных массивах самое большое значение price и/или count в порядке убывания. Возможно создать из этого массива новый, в котором ключи будут являтся позицией массива по самым высоким значениям.
То есть, чтобы после сортировки по `count` массив был приблизительно такого вида:

> ```
>    $array = [
>       1     => [
>           'count'   => 55,
>           'price'   => 12512,
>       ],
>       2     => [
>           'count'   => 15,
>           'price'   => 974190,
>       ],
>       3     => [
>           'count'   => 14,
>           'price'   => 3125,
>       ]
>       4     => [
>           'count'   => 13,
>           'price'   => 312561,
>       ],
>     ];
> ```

Очень долго гуглил и сам разобраться не смог.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: `usort($data, $fn($a,$b) => $a['count'] <=> $b['count'])`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$array = [
      1     => [
          'count'   => 15,
          'price'   => 974190,
      ],
      2     => [
          'count'   => 13,
          'price'   => 312561,
      ],
      3     => [
          'count'   => 55,
          'price'   => 12512,
      ],
      4     => [
          'count'   => 14,
          'price'   => 3125,
      ]
    ];


// Сортировка массива (по убыванию), в соответствии со значением
arsort($array);

// Не меняя порядок следования элементов просто поменять ключи
print_r(array_values($array));

?>
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 55
            [price] => 12512
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 15
            [price] => 974190
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 14
            [price] => 3125
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 13
            [price] => 312561
        )

)
```

Comment: Это от части поможет, но мне массиве множество значений и в зависимости от ситуации мне необходимо сортировать по конкретному ключу (по его убыванию, либо нарастанию).

Comment: Теперь можно при помощи цикла foreach пройтись по ключ-значение.